# Triggering a task on composer DAG from file arrive event from Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-functions, airflow, google-cloud-composer

Can I trigger an airflow task from cloud function?

Basically my problem is this. I have some file which arrives in google cloud storage. Multiple files in the same DAG. I need to trigger a transformation job when the file arrives. I was thinking to use cloud function. But there are a lot of dependent jobs in my DAG.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 6):

You necessarily don't need Cloud Function to sense for the file in GCS, Composer has GCS sensors which can be used to fulfill the purpose.

Suppose you have to monitor files in bucket/folder/file_*.csv then :

```
from airflow.contrib.operators.gcs_list_operator import GoogleCloudStorageListOperator
    from airflow.contrib.sensors.gcs_sensor import GoogleCloudStoragePrefixSensor 
    import datetime as dt
    from airflow.models import DAG
    from airflow.operators.dagrun_operator import TriggerDagRunOperator

    lasthour = dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(hours=1)

    args = {
     'owner': 'airflow',
     'start_date': lasthour,
     'depends_on_past': False,
    }
    dag = DAG(
     dag_id='GCS_sensor_dag',
     schedule_interval=None,
     default_args=args
    )
    GCS_File_list = GoogleCloudStorageListOperator(
                        task_id= 'list_Files',
                        bucket= 'bucketname',
                        prefix='folder/file_',
                        delimiter='.csv',
                        google_cloud_storage_conn_id='google_cloud_default',
                        dag = dag
                    )
    file_sensor = GoogleCloudStoragePrefixSensor(
                        task_id='gcs_polling',  
                        bucket='bucketname',
                        prefix='folder/file_',
                        dag=dag
                    )

    trigger = TriggerDagRunOperator(
                        task_id='trigger_dag_{timestamp}_rerun'.format(timestamp=((dt.datetime.now() - dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)).total_seconds()*1000)),
                        trigger_dag_id="GCS_sensor_dag",
                        dag=dag
                    )

file_sensor >> GCS_File_list >> trigger
```

Comment: Hi! How to access these newly created/modified CSV files please in order to process them?

Comment: So, here the dag is triggered once manually, then on each sensor it triggers itself, something like an infinite loop, right?

Comment: I am pretty sure there is a mistake on this solution. OP asked for a DAG that would trigger a second transformation DAG upon sensing a new GCS file upload. This DAG triggers itself which is mistaken. Assuming there is a second transformation DAG, say, 'transform_DAG', the trigger should be instantiated as such:  

TriggerDagRunOperator(task_id = ..., trigger_dag_id = "transform_DAG", conf = {"file_to_transform": "my_file.csv"}). The transform DAG would then read the conf to know which file to transform.

Comment: Also, for this solution to work, your sensor DAG would need to be running at the time of a new file upload to GCS. This is hard to guarantee. Thus, I'd opt for the Cloud Function solution outlined below.

Answer (score 2):

You can trigger DAGs in response to a change in a Cloud Storage bucket. To accomplish this, Cloud Composer DAGs can be triggered by Cloud Functions. There is already great [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/triggering-with-gcf) and [Codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/triggering-dag-gcf/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0), which describe the workflow. It will work as following:

1. Upload a File to Cloud Storage bucket, which will
2. Trigger a Cloud Function using the Python/Node.JS runtime
3. This function will execute a DAG in Cloud Composer

Remember about one thing. When you will be at the `Creating your function` step. You need to fill that line: `const WEBSERVER_ID = 'your-tenant-project-id';`. 
To retrieve that variable, go to Airflow UI, than `Admin -> Configuration`, and search for `base_url` key, which is your `webserver-id` (without `https://` and `.appspot.com` parts).

Another way to do so, is using the following command:

```
gcloud composer environments describe <ENVIRONMENT_NAME> --location <LOCATION>
```

And you will be able to see config: -> `airflowUri` variable.

I've tried that scenario once and it works pretty fine. Feel free to ask more questions. I hope you find the above pieces of information useful.

Comment: Can I trigger a task from cloud composer function - I have multiple file listen jobs

Comment: Your arriving file into GCS bucket will trigger a Cloud Function, which will execute specified DAG(task) in Cloud Composer.

Comment: @muscat Cant we establish connection to cloud composer from cloud function without OAuth or service account?just like we connect to storage and firestore in cloud function.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible because Cloud Composer is shielded by Cloud Identity Aware proxy. DAGs are triggered externally from GCF and you need to identify the oauth2 client_id it uses .

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is difference between Cloud function and GoogleCloudStoragePrefixSensor. Cloud function triggers whenever any event occurs such as File arrival. that way there is guarantee that only the latest file will be picked up.
In contrast, GoogleCloudStoragePrefixSensor, it runs at predefined time (as part of DAG) and picks up EXISTING file, matching prefi, in given location. e.g. in daily job, today file arrived and it was processed. If that file continues to lie there, same file may be picked up by this sensor. So you need to be careful in its application. Ofcourse you can put addon intelligence to pick up latest file and archiving file once processed and all but that has to be added.

Answer (score -1):

To automate the process described, we can use a combination of Google Cloud Dataflow for both streaming and batch pipelines, Google BigQuery for data storage, and Apache Airflow for workflow management. Below is an overview of the logic, followed by a diagram and example code for the streaming and batch pipelines, as well as the first and second Airflow DAGs.

Logic:

1. The streaming dataflow pipeline continuously ingests data and stores it into BigQuery in near real-time.
2. Upon data storage in BigQuery, a trigger is sent to an Airflow DAG to start the batch dataflow pipeline.
3. The batch dataflow pipeline processes the data loaded into BigQuery.
4. Once the batch job is completed, it triggers the next batch job, and the process continues.

Diagram:

```
         +------------------+
         | Streaming Pipeline |
         |   (Dataflow)      |
         +--------+---------+
                  |
                  |
       +----------v-----------+
       |                      |
       |     BigQuery         |
       |                      |
       +----------+-----------+
                  |
                  |
    +-------------v-------------+
    |                           |
    |   Airflow DAG (Batch Job)  |
    |        (Dataflow)         |
    +-------------+-------------+
                  |
                  |
    +-------------v-------------+
    |                           |
    |   Airflow DAG (Batch Job)  |
    |        (Dataflow)         |
    +-------------+-------------+
```

Example code for the streaming pipeline (Dataflow):

```py
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

# Define pipeline options
pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()

# Define pipeline logic
def process_streaming_data(data):
    # Process streaming data here
    # Store data into BigQuery

# Create the pipeline
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    # Read streaming data source
    streaming_data = p | beam.io.ReadFromSource(...)
    
    # Apply processing logic
    processed_data = streaming_data | beam.ParDo(process_streaming_data)

    # Write to BigQuery
    processed_data | beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(...)
```

Example code for the batch pipeline (Dataflow):

```py
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

# Define pipeline options
pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()

# Define pipeline logic
def process_batch_data(data):
    # Process batch data here

# Create the pipeline
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    # Read data from BigQuery
    batch_data = p | beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(...)
    
    # Apply processing logic
    processed_data = batch_data | beam.ParDo(process_batch_data)

    # Write results to a sink (e.g., BigQuery, GCS, etc.)
    processed_data | beam.io.WriteTo...

    # Trigger the next batch job
    p.run().wait_until_finish()
```

Example code for the first Airflow DAG:

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.dataflow_operator import DataFlowPythonOperator
from datetime import datetime

# Define DAG configuration
dag_config = {
    'start_date': datetime(2023, 6, 1),
    'schedule_interval': '@daily',
}

# Define the DAG
dag = DAG('streaming_batch_pipeline', default_args=dag_config)

# Define the Dataflow task
streaming_pipeline_task = DataFlowPythonOperator(
    task_id='streaming_pipeline_task',
    py_file='<path_to_streaming_pipeline_file>',
    options={'streaming': True},
    dag=dag
)

# Define the trigger for the batch pipeline
trigger_batch_pipeline_task = DataFlow

PythonOperator(
    task_id='trigger_batch_pipeline_task',
    py_file='<path_to_batch_pipeline_file>',
    options={'streaming': False},
    dag=dag
)

# Set task dependencies
streaming_pipeline_task >> trigger_batch_pipeline_task
```

Example code for the second Airflow DAG (to be triggered by the first DAG):

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.dataflow_operator import DataFlowPythonOperator
from datetime import datetime

# Define DAG configuration
dag_config = {
    'start_date': datetime(2023, 6, 1),
    'schedule_interval': '@daily',
}

# Define the DAG
dag = DAG('batch_pipeline', default_args=dag_config)

# Define the Dataflow task
batch_pipeline_task = DataFlowPythonOperator(
    task_id='batch_pipeline_task',
    py_file='<path_to_batch_pipeline_file>',
    options={'streaming': False},
    dag=dag
)
```

Please note that the example code provided is a simplified representation, and you would need to fill in the actual logic and configurations specific to your use case, such as data source details, BigQuery table schema, pipeline options, etc.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).

Comment: @tchrist Not to mention that as usual ChatGPT style it cannot answer difficult questions. It serenades about the details of DAG and things like that, but more important portion of the question is the trigger mechanism and the Cloud Function. The user might have also asked some badly phrased question, because LLM attention mechanism usually can focus on the important stuff.